# ASP.NET Web API Post method always returns entire entity collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Whenever I call the `Post` method of my Web API controller it returns the list of entities in the JSON as if I was calling the `Get` method.  I've commented out the Get Methods in my controller and it still returns the list of entities in the database.  I'm using the Post method to create a new entity and that's working but I only want that new entity to be returned.  Here's my `ApiController` Post method.

```
// POST api/MyEntity
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyEntityDTO myEntityDTO)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyEntity newEntity = new MyEntity();
            newEntity.AccountId = myEntityDTO.AccountId;
            newEntity.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

            db.MyEntities.AddObject(newEntity);
            db.SaveChanges();


            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, newEntity);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = newEntity.EntityID }));                
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with routing but here is the default entry in `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

EDIT:  The table I was using to in the POST `MyEntities` has a `many-to-one` relationship with another table and a `one-to-many` relationship with another table.  I created a new table without relationships and used that in the POST.  This works as expected, it just returned the added entity and not all the records in that table.  Are entity relationships controlling what is returned?  Does this have something to do with Lazy or Explicit loading?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code step by step? It doesn't seem to be related to your POST since that looks ok. There doesn't seem to be a way to be returning all items here, unless something else is being called client-side or old code is being run.

Comment: Yes I have.  It goes directly from the `return response;` line to the `MyEntities.edmx` designer `MyEntities.Designer.cs`. This is the `ADO Entity Data Model`.  I used the database first approach.  While debugging it goes to the `Primitive Properties` in the designer.  It debugs through for all records in the table.  I've also looked at the network through the browser debugger and there isn't any call to the `Get`.

Comment: What is the response code of the "POST" request? is it really `HttpStatusCode.Created`?

Comment: @Liel Response Code is 201.  See my EDIT that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 MVC4 Web API Project, Database first with ADO Entity Data Model.  The entity I'm trying to add has `many-to-one` and `one-to-many` relationships with two tables.

Comment: could it be that the new record has a field that links to many other `MyEntityDTO`? and that in the result you actually see one `MyEntityDTO` record, with a field that is a list of all other `MyEntityDTO` records?

Comment: @Liel I turned LazyLoading off and it worked.  I think your comment was on track to the answer.  It was bringing back all the related records of the other tables.

Comment: Ok, i'm moving it to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the new record has a field that links to many other `MyEntityDTO`? and that in the result you actually see one `MyEntityDTO` record, with a field that is a list of all other `MyEntityDTO` records?

Carefully examine the JSON structure, and check if the root node is an Array or a single object.

If that is true, you might want to reconsider if your DTO actually need to have a field which is a list of other DTOs.